# In which places should I check for Firewall Rules in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, operating-system, packaging, windows-firewall, windows-application-packaging

I come from Application Packaging background and want to understand that once any application gets installed on the machine and it is creating any firewall rules. So at what places I shall check on windows, if any new rules are created/added ?

What I know so far is:

1. We can check in Registry editor in the following hives

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List

2. Through windows built in apps such as

- WF.MSC (Type this in Run to open "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security")
- GPEDIT.MSC (Type this in Run to open "Local Group Policy Editor")
- Local Security Policy (Search in StartMenu)
- Local Group Policy (Search in StartMenu)

Can anyone help understand that is there any other way to look for firewall rules or this is all the places one can look for firewall rules in windows 10?

What I am expecting is are there any other ways such as any PowerShell command that we can run and check or is there any other place in windows?

Comment: You shouldn't "check" the underlying storage, you should query the firewall service - the only authority on the matter: `Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore ActiveStore` to get the current active rules, `Get-NetFirewallRule -All` for all the defined rules